# Solve issue of relative positioned CSS elements appearing after a sticky element

Tags: css

When positioning an element as `sticky`, it would seem that any subsequent and adjacent elements that are positioned as relative will not scroll behind the sticky element.

I can't work out if this is intentional or a bug.

In my larger use case, I have a sticky element and in the following container I have a DataTables instance, which happened to style of it's elements as relative.

For a smaller demonstration, I have these three examples.

The first example is taken from https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/, and everything is working as intended.

Example 1: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/hewAv

The second example shows the whole `container` class as being relative.  When you scroll up and the menu becomes sticky, the content of the `container` class scrolls in front of the sticky container.

Example 2: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKzEBZ

The third example shows the first paragraph in the `container` class as being relative. When you scroll up and the menu becomes sticky, the content of the `relative` class scrolls in front of the sticky container, while the other content scrolls behind.

Example 3: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdwvEY

I'd like to find a solution where the relative content will scroll behind the sticky element.

---

Answers to question comments:

- The examples are all using `position: sticky'.
- I've tried using Chrome 57 and Firefox 52.0a2.

Comment: You're aware of browser support for `position: sticky`? Which browser are you testing on?

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the relative element a z-index of -1 so it appears behind that sticky element.

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Or give the sticky element a z-index higher than that of every other element on the page so it's always on top.